# Reporting to Sentry to proof that it's working, like on start up?

Tags: spring-boot, sentry

We are using [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) for finding some errors.

How do you proof, that a reporting is working?
I had a Spring-Boot project, which was not sending any error to Sentry, so it looks like it was working without an error, but I saw in [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana), that there have been errors.
So, my configuration was wrong. After fixing the setup, it's now sending the errors to Sentry too.

Is there any way to proof that the sending to Sentry is working?
Something like on startup of my Spring-Boot application sending a first string?

I found 2 possible solutions which both sucks, so that's why I ask for a more professional way:

1. I can make just on [application start up](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/13/run-code-at-spring-boot-startup/) a log.error("sentry is working")
2. I can set the log-level from warning / error to info just to see that it's working and if  see it in Sentry, you change it back?

But as i mentioned, both methods are not good, so let me know how you are resolving problems like this
are unprofessional to me, so let me know

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a real "answer" here currently, as part of Sentry's simplicity is it doesn't do anything until an error happens. One potential solution is to introduce a path like example.com/500 that deliberately errors.

Comment: You could also manually log out to Sentry on Sentry application initialization. It will count as an "event" (if you're using hosted Sentry) and will show up in your issue stream, but should work fine and, so long as it's only on startup and not on every request, it shouldn't produce significant load.

Comment: can you write little bit more too it? just to get it right: I want to test if the project setup with sending everything to sentry is completly working... but maybe i just don't get it yet, what you mean.